# What is the correct way to check whether an audio file is corrupted or not in iOS?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

My iOS App plays an audio file. Before playing audio file, To handle any exceptions I'm checking whether the file is corrupted or not by the following code.

```
NSData *mediaFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; //Here the 'url' is Local audio file path url
NSError *mediaError;
AVAudioPlayer *obj = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:mediaFile error:&mediaError];
if (mediaError) {
    NSLog(@"mediaError-->%@",[mediaError localizedDescription]);
}
```

This checking of audio file is not working properly.
My audio file is not corrupted, It is playing well in mac, But this code is still giving me some error like

> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1685348671 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)"

Am i doing something wrong here?

Please suggest me the correct way to check whether an audio file is corrupted or not in iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be the format for the audio is not supported by the device.

Comment: might be first check the media file data using method 
dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error: Check to be sure there is no issue in getting data.

Comment: @Kampai I'm using .m4a format.

Comment: @rishi I'm getting NSData correctly. There is no error with file data.

Comment: Have a look on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490989/avaudioplayer-initialization-error