# MP3 file from server is not playing with AVAudioPlayer in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

Here is my code, In this first I am calling mp3 url for downloading the audio data. then I am saving that data in local directory, After that I am playing audio from local file path but its not working `AVAudioPlayer` throwing error. I have tried some other ways also but no one work for me.
On simulator same code is working fine.
And the audio url is playing like a charm in browser.

```
 NSURL *urlll=[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.xyz.audio.mp3"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlll] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *responce,NSData* data,NSError * error) {
        if (error == nil)
        {
            indicator.hidden=YES;
            [indicator stopAnimating];

            if (data)
            {
               NSString *docDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp3", docDirPath , @"Audio"];
                [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

              NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
                AudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];

                AudioPlayer.delegate=self;
                [AudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
                if (AudioPlayer == nil) {
                    NSLog(@"AudioPlayer did not load properly: %@", [error description]);
                } else {
                    [AudioPlayer play];

                }
           }
      }
}];
```

But I am getting these kind of errors : E`rror Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1685348671 "The operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)`

Please Help me :( .

Comment: Is this code in your viewDidLoad?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490989/avaudioplayer-initialization-error

Comment: NO , This code is calling from tableview did select.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you save the audio to `NSString *filePath` but you initiate with `fileURL`. Could it be that you actually wanted to do this:

```
AudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] error:&error];
```

If not then you should know that the error is reporting to you a `kAudioFileInvalidFileError`. Which means the file is malformed. You could try other formats like .`caf` or .`aifc` or `aiff`.

--edit--

Make sure the `AVAudioPlayer` is a property in .m or .h file, so the memory allocation lasts after leaving the method:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) AVAudioPlayer *AudioPlayer;
```

(side note: properties should start with **lowercase** -> `audioPlayer`)

Comment: I have tried all the formats and getiing , The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)

Comment: This issue is only with iOS7 on updated devices everything working fine.

Comment: How is your **AudioPlayer** property declared?

Comment: In .h like this AVAudioPlayer *AudioPlayer;

Comment: I have tried this @property (nonatomic,strong) AVAudioPlayer *AudioPlayer;

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.  Did you found the answer?